# Cable size for 400 W solar PV, 7 m long run

Tags: solar-cell

I have 2 Renergy 19.2 V 200 W panels, the rated current for each is 35 A. I intend to wire them in series, and the cable run to the grid tie inverter is 7 m in length. Looking up on the Internet it looks like I will need 10 mm² cable. But when I look on the supplier sites they indicate 10 mm² is for much bigger installations than I am doing.
I am confused.

Link to the panel:
[Renogy 200 Watt 12 Volt Monocrystalline Solar Panel](https://uk.renogy.com/200-watt-12-volt-monocrystalline-solar-panel/)

Comment: Turns out these panels are roughly 20V at 10A. Not 35W. Or even 35A. Even the short circuit current is only about 11A.

Comment: The shorter and thicker the cable, the lower the voltage drop for a given current. So you need to decide how long the cables need to be and how much voltage drop you can accept at 11 A.

Comment: Yes, it is entirely unclear why the rated current is 35 A - to allow paralleling 3(…6) panels? Even 200 W/12 V would be 16.7 A, only. Then again, insolate it with 5 kW and exceed current rating with a single panel (and max temperature even without current more likely than not).

Comment: Thank you all. I'm even more confused now though. So for 7m long run, I think use 6mm2 safely instead. Does that sound correct?

Comment: How much cable losses can you tolerate?

Comment: @winny - It's not really about tolerating more or less. Any saving I can make in this world of high electricity prices is a benefit. Obviously, if I can lose less, that is better for me as I will start to see gains over fewer months.

Comment: Then you should use several hundred square mm. If you calculate the cost of it compared to what the losses are and how much those are worth to you, you’ll find it comes down to the economics and it would have been cheaper to buy more PV panels instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the actual [datasheet](https://store-nkm2yhe9h8.mybigcommerce.com/content/files/RSP200D-G3%20Datasheet.pdf):

```
Open Circuit Voltage (Voc) 23 V
Short Circuit Current (Isc) 11.05 A
Output Cables 14 AWG (2.6 ft long)
```

So the cables attached to the panels are 14AWG (2mm²) which is adequate for 11.05A.

The 35A spec is actually the MC4 connector's maximum current spec. It's not a useful number here because the 2mm² cable isn't rated for this current.

```
Maximum Series Fuse Rating 20 A
```

Now this makes sense for 2mm² cables.

If you use only 2 panels in series, you don't need a fuse.

So what is the fuse for? Suppose you use, say 3-4 strings of 2 series panels, and wire these strings in parallel. Then one of the panels shorts. All the other strings will dump all their current into the string with the shorted panel, and since we have 3 strings remaining, that would be more than 30 amps. That would destroy the string with the shorted panel. So we put a fuse on each string to prevent this. But if you only have one string, it can't happen.

Anyway it's only 11.05A so you can use any cable rated for that.

[Resistance for 14m](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wire-resistance) of 4mm² wire is 60 mOhm, at 11.05A that's 7 watts total loss, or 3.6% of 400W.

[Resistance for 14m](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wire-resistance) of 6mm² wire is 40 mOhm, at 11.05A that's 4.9 watts total loss, or 2.4% of 400W.

Since your panels are low voltage, it would not be necessary to use high voltage rated solar cable. But I'd still recommend solar cable, because it is the right diameter to make a watertight seal with the rubber ring at the back of MC4 connectors.

Comment: A great explanation, especially about the fusing of the "strings". So as the cost of 4mm2 vs 6mm2 is nominal for the length (7 m) I need, I will go for the 6mm2 so my losses will be slightly less. 
Great information about the sealing in the Mc4 / T4 connectors too.

Comment: Thanks! If you crimp your MC4 connectors yourself make sure to use the proper tool and take care. If the crimp makes a bad contact that's where it catches fire. It's possible to buy pre-made cables with MC4 connectors too.

Comment: That is another good tip about correct crimping, thanks. I have a crimp tool, but I will ensure it is compatible.